# Using AWK or SED to prepend a single_quote to each line in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I am working with ffmpeg and want to automate making one big video from many smaller.  I can use a list file, but each line Must Be `file 'name.ext'`. I can't figure out how to get sed or awk to NOT see the `'` as a control character. Any way to do that?

I have tried using a variable as instead of the string `file '`, tried a two statement script where i set `file @` then use another cmd to change the `@` to `'`, but it fails every time

```
awk '{print "line @"  $0}' uselessInfo.txt >goofy2.txt
sed '/@/\'/g' goofy2.txt >goofy3.txt
```

tried the sed line with `"` around the `'` also

Comment: Where exactly do you want the single quotes added? Your post title says to prepend it, but your examples seem to have in the middle with assorted other words prepended?

Comment: Did you see the section about "Automatically generate the input file" on the [help page for Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)?

Comment: The quick and dirty fix is to change your sed command to `sed "s/@/'/g"`, but instead, you should generate `uselessInfo` with the proper quotes in the first place. Also, dirty fix probably won't work because it's missing the closing quote – it's just fixing the outermost deficiency in your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sed nor awk are seeing `'` as a control character. In fact they aren't seeing the `'` at all in the code you posted - the **shell** doesn't allow you to use single quotes inside a single quote delimited script.

Your question isn't clear. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ echo 'foo' | awk '{print "file \047" $0 "\047"}'
file 'foo'

$ echo 'foo' | sed 's/.*/file '\''&'\''/'
file 'foo'

$ echo 'foo' | sed "s/.*/file '&'/"
file 'foo'
```

If not then edit your question to clarify and provide a concrete example we can test against.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a single quote at the front of each line:

```
> cat test.txt
a
b
c
> sed "s/^/'/" test.txt
'a
'b
'c
```

You can then output this to whatever file you wish as in your example.
The solution to your problem, I believe, lies in the fact that characters within single quotes on the command line are not interpreted.  This means that when you try to escape a quote inside a single quoted string, this will not work and you just get a backslash in your string.  Comparing this to a string bound by double quotes, we see that the backslash *is* interpreted before being passed to the command `echo` as an argument.

```
> echo '\'
\
> echo "\""
"
```

Answer (score 0):

another useful trick is defining single quote as a variable

```
$ echo "part 1" | awk -v q="'" '{print "line " q $0 q}'

line 'part 1'
```